# (java.lang.NoSuchMethodError) java.nio.file.Files.lines(Ljava/nio/file/Path;) in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am getting the following error in my IntellijIDEA Community Edition 2017.3 version. The project is using java version "1.8.0-ea". Please give me some ideas to resolve the issue

```
Error:Internal error: (java.lang.NoSuchMethodError) java.nio.file.Files.lines(Ljava/nio/file/Path;)Ljava/util/stream/Stream;
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.nio.file.Files.lines(Ljava/nio/file/Path;)Ljava/util/stream/Stream;
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsProjectLoader.getDirectoryBaseProjectName(JpsProjectLoader.java:102)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.Utils.getDataStorageRoot(Utils.java:91)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.Utils.getDataStorageRoot(Utils.java:60)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:208)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:138)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:235)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler$$Lambda$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl.lambda$executeOnPooledThread$0(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:42)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl$$Lambda$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Comment: could u post your code?

Comment: Switch to the latest Java 8 release version.

Comment: Thanks @CrazyCoder switched to java 1.8.0_162 and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Using the release Java version (vs the EA) should help.